# Add row to table inside a loop error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a table inside a loop, and I want to add a row to the table by clicking a button "add row". Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div id="popUp" style="display: none">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="closePopup()">
    <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="addRow(this)"/>
</div>
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    <table id="table @i" class="tableSum">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Items</td> 
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>Apple</td>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>100</td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Organe</td>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>200</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <td>Total</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
             <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="button" class="addRow" onclick="addRow(this)" value="ADD ROW"/></td></tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
}
```

then in javascript i wrote function:

```
function addRow(table) {
    $(table).find('tbody tr:last').clone().appendTo(table);
}
```

but it does not add a row. If I use the function without parameter "table", the new row will be added to all tables inside a loop.
My desired outcome is: When the user clicks the button a new row will be added only in the one table, not to all.

Comment: You can use this plugin to clone html element. It easy to use. https://github.com/metallurgical/jquery-metal-clone

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find its parent table first:

```
function addRow(table) {
    $(table).closest('table')//find parent table
      .find('tbody tr:last')//find last tr of the table
      .clone()//clone it
      .appendTo($(table).closest('table').find('tbody'));//append it to tbody
  //append to 'tbody' not this row
}
```

---

As per your updated question, here you go:

```
function addRow(table) {
    $(table).parent()//find parent div
      .next()//get the table
      .find('tbody tr:last')//find last tr of the table
      .clone()//clone it
      .appendTo($(table).parent().next().find('tbody'));//append it to tbody
  //append to 'tbody' not this row
}
```

Comment: it works now, one more question, how can i use closest property if the scenes changes like: After click button "Add row"  a poop up appear with 2 buttons "Cancel" and "OK". I'm confuse about this case, because this time, the button does not belong to any table

Comment: You're giving id to table, so you can target that table $('table#tableId').find()....

Comment: but if you want to get using $(this) then find it using next() or previous() or something what matches....

Comment: there are 3 buttons add rows in this example, how can i set the target table for them

Comment: within the same table the button exists?

Comment: <div id="popUp" style="display: none">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="closePopup()">
    <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="addRow(this)"/>
</div> here this the code i added. is this possible to keep using addRow(this)

Comment: then, how will you be sure in which table to append?

Comment: that what i confuse about, each table have 1 button "add row" so the row will be added to table of clicked button.

Comment: Oh, you mean you have same structure for all table and different buttons for the table? then do: $(table).parent().next()..find('tbody tr:last')....

Comment: i tried this code, but it only add row to the first table whenever i click any add row button

Answer (score 2):

`onclick="addRow(this)"` on a `td`. `this` will represent the surrent `td`. Not the `table`. You may pass the `id` or some selector of the table or find the parent `table` in with your script.

You can use `parents()` to find the parent `table`.

```
function addRow(td) {
    var table = $(td).parents('table');
    var cloned = table.find('tbody tr:last').clone();
    table.find('tbody').append(cloned);
}
```

And also if you want all the events to work then use `clone(true)`. Else you have to `bind` the events to the `tr`.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Unnecessarily clone? Then what would be appended?

Comment: what do use mean by "And also if you want all the events to work then use clone(true). Else you have to bind the events to the tr." can you explain more

Comment: @TranDuyLinh When you `clone` the `tr` the events like `click`, `change` will not work on them after appending. For this you have to bind them with the element.

Comment: what if i add a popup to the screen. i edited question